# What is the difference between "Soccer" and "Football"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

I am very confused about these two words. I mean these two words are used interchangeably. which make new comer so much confused. i need full explanation which can differentiate these two words with examples.
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Soccer" is the word for the sport in America, South Africa, Australia, New Zealand, South-East Asia, and Japan (or a closely related pronunciation).  "Football" is the word for the sport in the United Kingdom and Europe, along with some other places.  The country where the speaking person learned English is the only difference between these words.

And be careful, because an American will use the word "fooball" to describe a completely different sport, similar in appearance to rugby but with different rules.

It may help to [see this article and map by Business Insider.](https://www.businessinsider.com/football-vs-soccer-map-2013-12)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Map shows which countries call it 'football' and which call it 'soccer']
All these countries use different words, Which all refers to the game with 11 players on each side. All these blue countries in the map have a word "football" which genrally refers to "American football". More information about [American football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_football).

Comment: In Australia, football rarely, if ever, refers to American football. In most Australian states football usually refers to Australian Rules Football. In New South Wales and Queensland, football is more likely to refer to Rugby League Football. A smaller percentage of people in Australia would, amongst themselves, regard football as referring to Rugby Union Football.

Answer (score 1):

Football is a term for a number of sports that use balls, the hands and feet in various ways depending on the rules of the particular sport.

Some versions of football are quite old the Royal Shrovetide Football match played in the town of Ashborne in Derbyshire, England has been played since the 12th century.

These various versions of football were played to their own rules until the middle of the 19th century when improved education, printing and communications all came together to allow the various games to codify their own rules.

In this era the various versions of football, Association Football, Rugby Football League, Rugby Football Union, Australian Rules Football etc. had their rules set down.

Soccer is a shortening of the term Association Football first coined in England, but that has become more commonly used as a term for the sport in America, Australia and some other countries. In these countries there is often a local version of the sport such as Australian Rules Football or the NFL that is considered football for that country, or they are in the sphere of influence of a country that uses football to describe another sport such as Japan's relationship with America after WW2 ( also the reason why Baseball is popular there).

Football is commonly used as the name for Association Football in the UK although some diehard fans of Rugby League or Union will  refer to it as soccer.

As the map Aiden Stewart has linked shows many other countries use a version of football to describe Association Football as a sport.